# unresolved external symbol _stricoll

Tags: python, c++, windows

I am moving a Python Library to Windows platform which is depend on some c code.
However, I failed to build it under Windows, and got:

```
util.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _strtoll
```

The bad code is:

```
x_space[j].index = (INT64)strtoll(idx,&endptr,10);
```

My Compiler is VS2010, which used under XP 32bit.
And my make file is:

```
CXX = cl.exe
CFLAGS = /nologo /O2 /EHsc /I. /D _WIN32 /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
TARGET = .

lib: util.c
$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -LD util.c /Iliblinear -Fe$(TARGET)\util -link -DEF:util.def
```

How could I fix this problem?

Comment: The [`strtoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function is new in the C99 standard, and until very recently the Visual Studio compiler and standard library had very little support for C99. Actually, the [MSDN page for `strtoll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn320180.aspx) reports its availability only from VS2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft standard C library doesn't contain a definition for `strtoll()` which converts from a C string to a long long.

MS provides another function, called [`_strtoi64()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h80404d3.aspx), which does the same thing, and has exactly the same signature - just use it or define a macro for `strtoll` under MSVC.

```
__int64 _strtoi64(
   const char *nptr,
   char **endptr,
   int base 
);
```

Comment: I have tried ``strtoi64`` but also got ``unresolved external symbol`` error. Why?

Comment: Have you put underline to the beginning of the function (`_strtoi64`)? It is defined in the `stdlib.h`, are you sure it is a linker error?